# How to automatically update date fields in mongoDB collection on insert/update documents?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I'm using MongoDB v3.6.3 with PyMongo.
Here's my document structure:

```
{
  "process_id": number,
  "created_dttm": date,
  "updated_dttm": date
}
```

I want to do two things:

1. Whenever a new document is inserted, **created_dttm** and **updated_dttm** should have the current system date.
2. Whenever an existing document is updated, **updated_dttm** should be updated to the current system date at that time

I have done this using MongoEngine Models by overriding the save() and update() methods .

Is there any other way to do this using PyMongo other than explicitly handling this programatically while insert/update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't come out of the box from mongodb/pymongo. The only thing you get is if you use ObjectId's as primary keys for your documents, you can extract the timestamp from it with

```
oid = ObjectId()
oid.generation_time    # is a datetime.datetime
```

For the update timestamps, you'll need to handle that in your application code. There is usually 2 ways for doing this, either you emit & store `audit events` in a separate collection, either you wrap your update method and modify a `last_update_timestamp` every time it is called.